# Eliminar nodo dinámicamente con botón y modal usando JQuery y Bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, bootstrap, bootstrap-4

En mi HTML tengo un conjunto de entradas cuyo `id` sigue la forma `entry-<count>`. Las entradas poseen un botón de eliminación de sí misma (**Delete**), este muestra una ventana modal de Bootstrap 4; esta ventana posee una confirmación de la eliminación de la entrada (**Yes**) y un botón de cancelar. Esta ventana modal se utiliza para confirmar la eliminación de todas las entradas, una a la vez, funcionamiento que consigo utilizando el atributo `data-entry-number` del botón presionado, que también se utiliza para controlar el valor del `data-target` del botón **Yes** del modal.

En general, la actualización de los atributos y el modal, dependiendo de la entrada en cuestión, funciona correctamente (ver instrucciones JavaScript para `#delete-modal`); sin embargo, las instrucciones que eliminan la entrada y actualizan los parámetros funcionan una sola vez (la primera vez que se borra una entrada).

Desde el navegador se puede ver cómo el texto del `span` `#entry-number` y el `data-target` del botón **Yes** (`#delete-confirm`) se actualizan correctamente, lo que en teoría permitiría una eliminación correcta de cualquier entrada según el botón **Delete** presionado, pero desde la consola de Javascript, una vez eliminada la primera entrada, al imprimir el valor del la variable `entry_target` se obtiene el valor correspondiente a la primera entrada eliminada, por lo que para las subsiguientes no ocurre ninguna eliminación. Acá les dejo los códigos que ejemplifican este funcionamiento.

¿Qué está ocurriendo? No soy experto en Javascript y ver que el DOM está cambiando, y que pareciera ser que las instrucciones no ven esos cambios, me trae muy enredado. :) Me encantaría ver una respuesta que no solo me ayude con la solución, sino que también me explique los conceptos básicos que estoy perdiendo (espero que no sean demasiados).

```js
$('#delete-modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
 var $button = $(e.relatedTarget);
  var entry_number = $button.data('entry-number');
  $(this).find('#entry-num').text(entry_number);
  $(this).find('#delete-confirm').attr('data-target', '#entry-' + entry_number);
}).on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
 $(this).find('#entry-num').text('');
  $(this).find('#delete-confirm').attr('data-target', '');
});

$('#delete-confirm').on('click', function () {
   var entry_target = $(this).data('target');
   var $target = $(entry_target);
   $target.remove();
   $('#delete-modal').modal('hide');
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Test Buttons</h1>
    <div id="entry-1">
      <h3>Entry 1</h3>
      <p>Text of entry 1</p>
      <button data-entry-number="1" class="btn btn-outline-danger " type="button" aria-label="Delete" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete-modal" title="Delete">
      Delete
      </button>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div id="entry-2">
      <h3>Entry 2</h3>
      <p>Text of entry 2</p>
      <button data-entry-number="2" class="btn btn-outline-danger " type="button" aria-label="Delete" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete-modal" title="Delete">
      Delete
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal fade" id="delete-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalTitle"
        aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
         <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
               <h5 class="modal-title" id="modalTitle">Delete entry?</h5>
               <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
               </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
               Are your sure you want to delete the entry number <span id="entry-num"></span>?
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
               <button id="delete-confirm" data-target="" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Yes</button>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Después de darle unas cuantas vueltas me he encontrado con [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22725281/how-do-you-update-an-existing-bootstrap-modal-data-target) explicación a tu problema. A modo de resumen, la función data no setea el valor de `data-target`, de ahí que en el evento `$('#delete-confirm').on('click')`, al hacer `var entry_target = $(this).data('target');` te esté obteniendo el data-target del primer elemento. Para solucionarlo hay que obtener el data-target con la función `attr()` `var entry_target = $(this).attr('data-target');` (de hecho en el `show.bs.modal` ya lo estás asignando bien con `attr()`)

```js
$('#delete-modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
 var $button = $(e.relatedTarget);
  var entry_number = $button.data('entry-number');
  $(this).find('#entry-num').text(entry_number);
  $(this).find('#delete-confirm').attr('data-target', '#entry-' + entry_number);
}).on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
 $(this).find('#entry-num').text('');
  $(this).find('#delete-confirm').attr('data-target', '');
});

$('#delete-confirm').on('click', function () {
   var entry_target = $(this).attr('data-target');
console.log($(this).data('target'));
   console.log($(this).attr('data-target'));
   var $target = $(entry_target);
   $target.remove();
   $('#delete-modal').modal('hide');
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Test Buttons</h1>
    <div id="entry-1">
      <h3>Entry 1</h3>
      <p>Text of entry 1</p>
      <button data-entry-number="1" class="btn btn-outline-danger " type="button" aria-label="Delete" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete-modal" title="Delete">
      Delete
      </button>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div id="entry-2">
      <h3>Entry 2</h3>
      <p>Text of entry 2</p>
      <button data-entry-number="2" class="btn btn-outline-danger " type="button" aria-label="Delete" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete-modal" title="Delete">
      Delete
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal fade" id="delete-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalTitle"
        aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
         <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
               <h5 class="modal-title" id="modalTitle">Delete entry?</h5>
               <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
               </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
               Are your sure you want to delete the entry number <span id="entry-num"></span>?
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
               <button id="delete-confirm" data-target="" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Yes</button>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Es extraño, pues en esa instrucción solo estoy consultando un valor, no intentando establecerlo. Pero sí, al cambiar por `attr` funciona.

Comment: Sí, pero no tienen el mismo valor. Realmente estás asignando en el show.bs.modal con attr(). Con el data() sólo asignas el primer elemento a borrar (si el primero es #entry-1 se asigna ese, si no el #entry-2) y ya no lo vuelves a modificarlo. No sé si me he explicado muy bien...